# Ruby On Rails - Form Select info from database

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, forms, select, hash

I have this line of code:

```rb
<%= f.select(:state, :id, Location.all.collect { |l| [ l.location, l.id] }, {:class => "form-select"}) %>
```

but it keeps throwing a: **no implicit conversion of Array into Hash**

Comment: just remove the `:id` param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s say you want to be able to select the state and it's id as a part of your params hash.

Rails provides [select_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) helper in conjunction with the [options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag#54-select-tag-with-options-for-select-example) helper so you can create these in your view by just iterating over collection.

`options_for_select` expects a very specific input – an array of arrays which provide the text for the dropdown option and the value it represents. This is great, because that’s exactly what your part of code does `Location.all.collect { |l| [ l.location, l.id] }`

Example:

```rb
<%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(Location.all.collect { |l| [ l.location, l.id] }),{:class => "form-select"}) %>
```

So, `options_for_select(Location.all.collect { |l| [ l.location, l.id] })` will create a couple of option tags, one for each choice, like this: *options_for_select([["choice1",1],["choice2",2]])*

Also, if you want to avoid the `options_for_select` option, you can you use generic [`select` helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).